# Can't use mkstemp(char *) in mingw32

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, mingw32

I have a C++ code that was written for linux originally, that uses `mkstemp`. I'd like to be able to keep using `mkstemp` regularly throughout the code as I port it to windows, compiling with `MinGW32`. `mkstemp` was added to `MinGW`, but when I've looked at the `MinGW` `stdlib.h`, its version of `mkstemp` is behind a few `ifdefs` testing for a posix-compliant system.

I am receiving *not declared in scope* errors.

How are people using `mkstemp`? What am I missing?

EDIT: No, this question is not a duplicate. I've read that other question, and my question is an extension of one of the comments/answers in there. Mainly "For the record, MinGW.org now provide mkstemp() and mkdtemp(), in releases of the MinGW runtime library, mingwrt-3.21 and later, (but not in the fatally flawed mingwrt-4.x variants, which have now been withdrawn from general release)."

Comment: What ifdefs in particular?

Comment: sorry, not ifdefs, just ifs. #if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >=200112L but they seem to be layered in some weird way

Comment: [You define those macros in your programs.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html)

Comment: hm, I'll look into that.